# Make a piano using NASM on linux x86_64

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I recently want to make piano using assembly using NASM on Linux, i got example on DOS 16-bit what service i can use and where can i put the frequency value? i already declared the frequency like below:

```
C: DW 4560
D: DW 4063
E: DW 3619
F: DW 3416
G: DW 3043
A: DW 2711
B: DW 2415
C.: DW 2280
```

and i try comapare and push it into AX register:

```
Cmp RAX,49
    Je Do_C
    Jmp Error

    Cmp RAX,50
    Je Re_D
    Jmp Error

    Cmp RAX,51
    Je Mi_E
    Jmp Error

    Cmp RAX,52
    Je Fa_F
    Jmp Error

    Cmp RAX,53
    Je Sol_G
    Jmp Error

    Cmp RAX,54
    Je La_A
    Jmp Error

    Cmp RAX,55
    Je Si_B
    Jmp Error

    Cmp RAX,56
    Je Do_C.
    Jmp Error

Do_C:
    Mov AX,word [C]
    Jmp Tone

Re_D:
    Mov AX,word [D]
    Jmp Tone

Mi_E:
    Mov AX,word [E]
    Jmp Tone

Fa_F:
    Mov AX,word [F]
    Jmp Tone

Sol_G:
    Mov AX,word [G]
    Jmp Tone

La_A:
    Mov AX,word [A]
    Jmp Tone

Si_B:
    Mov AX,word [B]
    Jmp Tone

Do_C.:
    Mov AX,word [C.]
    Jmp Tone
```

for further code in my [Github](https://github.com/AFOEK/KeyPressASM/blob/master/key.asm), Thanks for helping

Comment: You don't seem to have provided an actual problem in your question. Also, using the whole `rax` is excessive, I'd stick to just `eax`. Also, why do you jump to `Error` after every check? I'd expect to only do that on the last one, and simple fall through to the next check each time.

Comment: Why do you have those `Jmp Error` instructions? Don't you want to fall through to the next comparison? And why is there a period (`.`) after `Je Do_C` ?

Comment: The simplest thing to do with modern sound drivers (like ALSA) is send PCM sampled audio to the sound card.  If you have hardware (or driver-software) MIDI support, you might be able to use that as a tone-generator that takes a frequency, or maybe you could use the PC-speaker like you were with DOS.  But normally you'd generate sine waves yourself and loop them to the sound card.

Comment: Also, use an array, not a chain of branches!  Your values are linear and contiguous, so just `sub` to map them to a 0..7 index, and `movzx eax, word [table + rdi * 2]`.

Comment: @Michael i have ````Do_C.```` because i cannot use another symbol to represent the last note, for the jump its make sense i'll change it thanks bud :)

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry I still new linux assembly and the interface... can you explain more about the sine wave and the PCM ? thanks

Comment: @ThomasJager I like= to make an piano using nasm i stuck on how i push the frequency value to register and play it using speaker, for RAX register because i setup raw input

Comment: Nothing to do with asm, you'd have the same issue programming in C for GNU/Linux.  Modern sound drivers provide easy ways to play back sampled digital audio, e.g. with 16-bit stereo samples at 44.1 kHz.  Less easy access to tone-generators, unless they have a MIDI output.  e.g. [Stereo "tone-generator" for linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/82112) mentions https://web.archive.org/web/20170225125256/http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/jj/linux/siggen.html which generates a sampled sine wave and plays it back (via legacy /dev/dsp, so it's obsolete)

Comment: If you don't understand digital sampled audio (PCM being the simplest form), go watch the video lectures on https://www.xiph.org/video/ especially the 2nd one - Monty, the lead developer of Ogg Vorbis and other codecs, does a *very* good job, including real oscilloscopes.  Not too long, but packs a lot of info.

Comment: TL:DR: There is no super-simple API on GNU/Linux that lets you use a frequency number in Hz in a register to just make that tone, AFAIK.  Possibly via a library, but not with raw system calls.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes for the reference :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218330/discussion-between-felix-montalfu-and-peter-cordes).